# What is the best way to generate *non-repeating* securely random numbers?

Tags: random, uuid, birthday-paradox

I'm working on something that needs to assign securely random, short (~40 bit) IDs. They need to be unique, which means doing it on a central server.

Just using a new SecureRand each time would run into the birthday problem and start taking longer to generate new entries.

What would be a better method?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that 40 bits is way too short to avoid collisions if just choosing them randomly, even if you only need a few. Indeed, it's really too short to call them "secure" no matter which algorithm you use. However, assuming you need far fewer than the full trillion of them, and that you don't really need the security of a larger space, you really have only one choice: rejection sampling. I.e. generate randomly and compare with existing ones. This won't "start taking longer", as you put it, until you get really close to that trillion, because you can find used ones with an O(1) hash. Using something like a 40-bit cyclic generator that won't repeat and keeping track of only the "last" one won't be secure, and also makes parallelizing difficult.

Comment: They don't need to be secure in the strong cryptographic sense, given how I'm using them. See Ryan's comments on the [Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10G_AhiovtKoLVPGny5UdisSKE4StOLXLPiIZ6j1i1iM/edit?pli=1#), page 2 part 4(b). "Generate, see if exists, repeat if yes / output if no" is the default, but it'll run into 50% [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics) level @ ~2^20 entries, which is well under the expected # of assignments.

Comment: If you need anywhere close to 2^20 keys, then using a 40-bit key space is insane. You really need to question your assumptions here. Back up and take a fresh look at what you really need.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the google doc? This is not a standard question about cryptoanalytic attacks. The practical keyspace is severely limited by human usability, and it's just not subject to most of the attacks for which an extremely sparse space usage is obligatory.

Comment: I just read the doc--yes, 40 bits was chosen to represent a space that could reasonably grow to 2^30 assignments. That's probably enough headroom not to run out anytime soon (even if extended internationally), but yes, random ones WILL collide. So like I said, you're probably stuck generating them and checking the database. Just make sure the database is organized for fast comparison.

Comment: Thus the question: is there a better way to generate them (eg Ryan's suggestion), which iterates through a random permutation of the entire keyspace without repetition?

Comment: If you're the only one generating them, then sure, there are hundreds of ways. First, why be random at all, why not just generate them in a pre-defined order? If you really want them distributed in a more seemingly random way, then use something like a 40-bit LFSR or LCG.

Comment: Pre-defined order would disclose when a given ID was assigned, which is a privacy leak. Links for LFSR / LCG?

Comment: Jeez, do you want me to spell Google and Wikipedia for you too?  Do some research. But if that's your concern about pre-defined order, then NO deterministic generator will work because they're just as predictable no matter how seemingly "random" they are. You really do need a cryptographic generator. There's no way around it. Like I thought the first time: use a real random generator, and check for dups.

Comment: Ryan suggested using AES-FFX (and [previously](https://plus.google.com/103112149634414554669/posts/erpLgpxBQp5), a cryptographically secure pseudo-random permutation generator [CSPRPG]), which seemed to do what I described (assign random numbers without repetition). Do you think those wouldn't work?